# Issue with toggle function in Firefox (wufoo script inside both divs that are toggling)

Tags: jquery, firefox, toggle

I am having an issue with firefox displaying my toggled divs correctly. I have looked at other questions but none seem to cover the same problem.

I have a wufoo form in both of the div's that are being toggled, here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cheque-content').hide();
    $('.cheque-function').click(function(){
        $('div.cheque-content').toggle();
});
});
</script>
<h6 class="show-book cheque-function">Book by Cheque</h6>


    <div class="cheque-content">
    <p>sample paragraph</p>

    <div id="wufoo-q7p5z5">
Fill out my <a href="http://zulo.wufoo.com/forms/q7p5z5">online form</a>.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var q7p5z5;(function(d, t) {
var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
'userName':'zulo', 
'formHash':'q7p5z5', 
'autoResize':true,
'height':'1346',
'async':true,
'header':'hide', 
'ssl':true};
s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
try { q7p5z5 = new WufooForm();q7p5z5.initialize(options);q7p5z5.display(); } catch (e) {}};
var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');</script>
</div>
```

The other div follows the same code with different information, I am assuming that this has something to do with the wufoo script, does anyone have any idea why this isn't working in firefox? It works in all other browsers.

Thanks
Grant

Comment: Your code looks fine, have you checked if there are any errors thrown in Firebug?

Comment: Hi there, To be honest I rarely use firefox so don't know much about Firebug, but on the console it shows no errors.

Comment: If it helps, here is the link for the page: http://www.womenconnect.co.uk/events/negotiation-skills

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use a single form. Add a question to the form that asks if they want to pay by PayPal or Cheque. Then use Wufoo's rules feature so that cheque registrants are not sent to PayPal:

http://www.wufoo.com/2010/07/08/pay-by-check/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same exact issue today. I ended up having to change autoResize to false. This can cause other issues, like the iframe being cut off or too long. But at least it's functional. If you really do need the autoResize functionality, I would recommend dynamically injecting the Wufoo code after you unhide the div so that Wufoo can intelligently size the iframe.